# Is there a way to restrict the categories tag pair from displaying a category_group attached to an entry?

Tags: channel-entries, categories, category-group

I have tried using `category_group="4"` to restrict the categories displayed in the channel entries tag to ONLY that category group, but it's still displaying from category_group 14 as well. I then tried `category_group="not 14"` to try and restrict it from displaying those categories, but it changed absolutely nothing.

My news entries use 2 category groups, and I need to restrict it to only display categories attached to the entry from category_group 4. I may just be missing something...but it shouldn't be this hard to only display from one group.

Here is the code I'm currently using, and trying `category_group="4"` didn't help either:

```
{exp:channel:entries status="open|Featured" channel="{channel}" category="{cat}" orderby="date" limit="10" paginate="bottom"}
        <article>
            <figure><img src="{image_upload}" alt="{title}" /></figure>
            <div>
                <h4>{title}</h4>
                <p>{entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"} | Filed under: {categories backspace="7" category_group="not 14"}<a href="{path=news/view}">{category_name}</a>,&nbsp;{/categories}</p>
                {if news_body}<p><a class="more" href="{title_permalink=news/view}" title="Read More"> Read More &raquo;</a></p>{/if}
            </div>
        </article>
        {paginate}<p id="pagination">{pagination_links}</p>{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I would like to add that `show="not 97|98|99"` worked, as these are the exact categories in the group I would like to not show. I need a dynamic solution however, as these could be modified by the client in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in the `categories` tag pair, inside `exp:channel:entries`, the parameter you want is the [`show_group`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#show-group).

```
{exp:channel:entries status="open|Featured" channel="{channel}" category="{cat}" orderby="date" limit="10" paginate="bottom"}
        <article>
            <figure><img src="{image_upload}" alt="{title}" /></figure>
            <div>
                <h4>{title}</h4>
                <p>{entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"} | Filed under: {categories backspace="7" show_group="4"}<a href="{path=news/view}">{category_name}</a>,&nbsp;{/categories}</p>
                {if news_body}<p><a class="more" href="{title_permalink=news/view}" title="Read More"> Read More &raquo;</a></p>{/if}
            </div>
        </article>
        {paginate}<p id="pagination">{pagination_links}</p>{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

[`category_group`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/categories.html#category-group) is a parameter of the `exp:channel:categories` tag pair.

Comment: It also supports the "not", so to suit your purpose: show_group="not 97|98|99"

Comment: Thanks, show_group did the trick...I was obviously looking at the wrong categories documentation, lol.